# Change color of arrows in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

(English is not my native language, PROMT translate)

[image: Color of arrows]

Hello, how it is possible to change colors of arrows in Sublime Text 3? In my color scheme gray arrows on a black background, it is poor visibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrows in gutter see [answer Enteleform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36611930/5951529). For scroll tabs in active `*.sublime-theme` file add between `[]` :

```
// Tabs dropdown
{
"class": "show_tabs_dropdown_button",
"layer0.tint": [255, 182, 193],
"layer0.opacity": 1.0,
},
{
"class": "show_tabs_dropdown_button",
"attributes": ["hover"],
"layer0.opacity": 0.5,
},
{
"class": "scroll_tabs_left_button",
"layer0.tint": [0, 255, 0],
"layer0.opacity": 1.0,
},
{
"class": "scroll_tabs_left_button",
"attributes": ["hover"],
"layer0.opacity": 0.5,
},
{
"class": "scroll_tabs_right_button",
"layer0.tint": [0, 255, 0],
"layer0.opacity": 1.0,
},
{
"class": "scroll_tabs_right_button",
"attributes": ["hover"],
"layer0.opacity": 0.5,
},
```

`layer0.tint` — color in RGB, `layer0.opacity` — 0 ≥ transparency ≤ 1, `"attributes": ["hover"]` — properties when hover on the arrows.

[image: Scroll tabs color]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Fold button color can be specified in your active `*.sublime-theme` file via the `fold_button_control` `tint` property.

[image: demo]

This assumes that the `png` provided with your theme has mostly or entirely white contents, as white is the only color which is affected by the `tint` property.

You can also specify an alternative `png` at the `texture` property.

---

---

Here's the full set of related settings from my theme ( *a modified version of SpaceGray* ):

```
{
    "class": "fold_button_control",
    "layer0.texture": "Theme - Spacegray/Spacegray/folder-closed.png",
    "layer0.tint": [145, 159, 208],
    "layer0.opacity": 0.5,
    "layer0.inner_margin": 0,
    "content_margin": [8,8]
},
{
    "class": "fold_button_control",
    "attributes": ["hover"],
    "layer0.opacity": 1
},
{
    "class": "fold_button_control",
    "attributes": ["expanded"],
    "layer0.texture": "Theme - Spacegray/Spacegray/folder-open.png"
},
{
    "class": "fold_button_control",
    "attributes": ["expanded","hover"]
},
```

**Note:**
*I'm not sure if this will affect the arrows in the upper-left & upper-right of your screenshot, as they do not exist in my theme.*

Comment: 1. May I see documentation what to an element in [Default.sublime-theme](https://github.com/cj/sublime/blob/master/Theme%20-%20Default/Default.sublime-theme) there corresponds what class? For example, it is possible to assume that upper-left & upper-right arrows corresponds the class `"disclosure_button_control"`.  But when I added to my `Default.sublime-theme` file `{
     "class": "disclosure_button_control",
     "layer0.tint": [127, 255, 0],
     },`  , colors didn't change. Thanks.

Comment: 2. How I can increase brightness of arrows? I established color [chartreuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartreuse_%28color%29#Chartreuse_.28web_color.29) in RGBA: `{
    "class": "fold_button_control",
    "layer0.tint": [127, 255, 0, 255],
},` , but color of arrows turned out [too dim](http://pokit.org/get/img/4061ddf3a268c2fe19d608d8d4084ba2.jpg). Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных : **[1]** I believe the `disclosure_button_control` affects `sidebar` folders. I don't think there is any documentation for `sublime-themes` yet. My approach to customizing my theme was to just go through every single item and adjust it in realtime as I saw what was affected. **[2]** You can use RGB for `tint` & increase the `opacity` property.  In the example it's set at `0.5` opacity regularly & at `1` on `hover`. You can increase the regular opacity to `1` & add an alternate tint property to the `hover` variant if you want.

Comment: **[3]** Arrows have to be present always when openly there are a lot of tabs, it doesn't depend on the color scheme. [Example for Theme - Spacegray](http://pokit.org/get/img/90bd558a0e7f1279683c76f6ecf289a2.jpg).

Comment: @СашаЧерных : I think you installed `SpaceGray` but have not yet activated it, as SpaceGray doesn't have skeuomorphic tabs. Here is [**an image**](http://i.imgur.com/yQbQnFO.jpg) of my version of SpaceGray with a bunch of tabs.

Comment: **[4]** The maximum brightness to me managed to be achieved with `{
        "class": "fold_button_control",
        "layer1.tint": [0, 255, 255, 255],
        "layer1.opacity": 1.0,
    },`,  But color all the same turns out much more darkly, than real [0, 255, 255, 255](http://csscolor.ru/rgb/0,255,255). Whether there is even a way to increase brightness of arrows?

Comment: **[5]** What class at **[this](http://imgur.com/8DEr7jI)** Status Bar element? At me this element merges with a background, I want to change its color.  Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных : Check out [**SpaceGray.sublime-theme**](https://github.com/kkga/spacegray/blob/master/Spacegray.sublime-theme). It's pretty well documented with comments for each element, so you can read through them to see what options are available & search for particular elements that you would like to alter.

Comment: If in `Preferences` → `Settings - User` between `{}` add `"enable_tab_scrolling": true,` [arrows appear](http://www.sublimetext.ru/documentation/preferences/enable_tab_scrolling). Thanks.